# Does any connected metrizable space with more than one element have uncountably many open sets, each generating a connected subspace?

Tags: general-topology

> Moderator's note: I've copied the title of the post from a more recently posted version of this question by the OP. The text below is from the original question: I am not sure whether the motivations still applied, hence I left it untouched.

It is well known that any connected metrizable space with more than two points is uncountable. And any connected metrizable space has infinitely many open spheres; as each such sphere is connected, there are infinitely many connected subspaces. But must it be the case that any connected metrizable space has uncountably many connected subspaces?

Comment: Use [edit] to edit a question, instead of posting new ones.

Comment: @user156619 how does an open set generate a subspace? Or do you mean: does every connected metrisable space have uncountably many connected open subsets?

Comment: I've cleaned up the comments a bit, I left the one by @Henno as the newer version is still slightly different from what Henno proposed. And that the OP still has not answered what it means for "an open set to generate a subspace".